# Elasticsearch post_filter with array values

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to use a post_filter in my elasticsearch query but it is refusing to return any results when the post_filter is applied.

**Example of my data source**

```
{
    "_index": "foo",
    "_type": "products",
    "_id": "8eO0frchQeWNsY6t2EHqJQ",
    "_version": 1,
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "id": "32",
        "title": "Foo address book",
        "recipient": ["Him", "Her"],
        "category": ["Albums & Books>Address Books"]
    }
}
```

**Example of my query**

```
{
    "query":{"match_all":{}},
    "post_filter": {
        "terms": {"recipient": ["Her"]}
    }
}
```

As you can see, I /should/ be getting back all the rows with a post filter of "Her" applied to the recipient column. However, I'm getting back no hits with the post filter applied.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to type `her` lowercase in your query. Looks like your field is analyzed and terms filter on a field with default analyzer should be lowercase

Comment: Konstantin: that totally did it! Post as an answer and I will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to type `her` lowercase in your query.

Looks like your field is [analyzed](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html) and terms filter on a field with [default analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) should be lowercase